# How to get Session data in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

> Fatal error: Call to Undefined method CI_Session::get_userdata()
>   in/application/xamp/htdocs/application/models/articles_model.phI

I face a this error; how do I resolve this?

Comment: pls show your code also where you got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not correct method to get session data in code igniter.

To assign vale to session use

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name',$value);
```

To fetch value of session use

```
  echo $this->session->userdata('name');
```

To pass an array

```
$temp = array('name'=>'John Doe','login'=>1);
$this->session->set_userdata('details',$temp);
```

To get array session data

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('details'));
$details = $this->session->userdata('details');
echo $details['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Call to Undefined method **CI_Session::get_userdata()**
>
> **get_userdata()** change  into **userdata()**

Because it's the **userdata()** built-in session function in Codeigniter.
You can't change this